# What will be the alternative solution for Windows installer in VS 2019?

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

In Visual studio 2019 after the latest update I can't use Windows installer (incompatible), What will be the alternative solution for windows form deployment?[image]

Comment: Try these packages: [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)

Comment: this seem more appropriate for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can Use [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) For creating deployment packages for winforms.

Comment: If you think this answer helped you, you can just mark it as an answer.

Comment: We (at advanced installer) provide a free native extension for all versions of VS https://www.advancedinstaller.com/visual-studio-extension.html